# the virtual value in Text Box Asp.net MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I have  a text box in the Crete view in the asp.net mvc , and i want to put the virtual value 0 in this text box so when i save it will save in the database as 0 how i can do that?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NjNe.png)

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Credit, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Credit, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Credit, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        </div>
    </div>
```

this is the controller:

```
 // GET: DailyTransactions/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {

        var Customers = _context.Customers.ToList();

        List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>();

        foreach (var item in Customers)
        {
            list.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = item.Customer_Name, Value = item.Customer_Id.ToString() });

            ViewBag.Customers = list;
        }
        return View();
    }
```

To illustrate the idea i have in my project value in database name is credit so i want put this value as 0 i mean the virtual value 0 , so when i add some number to this credit the 0 will be increase .

so i Crete the text box and i want to put the virtual value 0 in this text box.

i hope you understand what i want.

thank you

Comment: You are wanting to set default value to `0`, isn't it?

Comment: yes , i edit the Question can you read again  plea?

Comment: Try this  `<input id="Text1" type="text" value="0" />`

Comment: can see the code in the Q i edit and i write the view code so how i cab put the 0 value in the text box ? so when i save it will save in the database as 0

Comment: Add your Create Get method to the question. I am answering.

Comment: It is better handle it from database by setting default value to 0.

Comment: how i can seating in the database?

Comment: @What is the model name in your create view?

Comment: DailyTransactions this is the name of model or table ,,, credit is the value

Comment: are you understand what i want ? i add pic so i want 0 in the text box and when i save it will save in database

Comment: @SoftwareDeveloper Use my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help, just copy and paste over your `EditorFor`

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Credit, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" , @Value = "0", @placeholder = "0",@min="0" })
```

As you can see I added the html attribute in the MVC html helper and added a min so the values below 0 will not be accepted.

Comment: @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Credit) could be useful.I suggest you do a little research on @Html.HiddenFor and MVC Helper attributes

Comment: Glad to be of help

Answer (score 1):

If you want to "suggest" a value without setting it, you use placeholder:

```
<input id="Text1" type="text" placeholder="0"/>
```

If you want to set a default value, then you set that value like this:

```
<input id="Text1" type="text" value="0" />
```

If you want to bind a value to your model, you use:

```
// your imports / declarations
@model myModel;

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

    // other html / razor code

    @Html.EditorFor(myModel => myModel.myNumber);
}
```

Comment: thank you ,, yes i want to bind a value to model but i don't understand your code 

i write this in the view ?

Comment: Yes, that's the code in your view. Obviously you have to implement "myModel" and also a controller, where you pass the model to the view.

Comment: can see the code in the Q i edit and i write the view code  so how i cab put the 0 value in the text box ? so when i save it will save in the database as 0